# No channel button in VSE preview

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

i am experimenting with the Video Sequencer and Multicam. I made several preview-Windows, but they all show the same channel. How can I map a specific channel to a specifig Preview-Window? I saw a Youtube-Tutorial, but it was on Blender 2.7, and there was a channel-selector on every preview-Window....but not anymore in my 2.83.4.

Comment: Press N to bring up the right-side panel and it's in the View tab

Comment: Ah, thank you! Is there any hotkey for this?